# React js - How to visualize images on top of a google-map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a small application that given the latitude and longitude of a vessel from [AIS Hub](https://www.aishub.net/api), will locate the boat and show its logo on a google-map. I mapped each company and each logo as shown below.

**The problem** I have is: after correctly looping through the companies provided as an answer from [AIS Hub API](https://www.aishub.net/api) and extracting the ones I need , I would like to match their logo and show it on a `google-map`.

Below the code that does almost what I need: I make the association but I am not able to visualize the images (or logo) of the companies on `google-map`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Table } from 'reactstrap';
import '../components/ShipTracker.css';

import donjonImage from '../logos/donjon.jpg';
import dutraImage from '../logos/dutra.png';
import glddImage from '../logos/greatlakesdredgeanddock.png';


const shipCompanyMap = {
  Michigan: 'DONJON',
  STUYVESANT: 'DUTRA',
  Ellis_Island: 'GREATLAKESDREDGEANDDOCK'
};

const companyImageMap = {
  DONJON: donjonImage,
  DUTRA: dutraImage,
  GREATLAKESDREDGEANDDOCK: glddImage,
};

const associationMap = Object.values(shipCompanyMap).reduce(
  (acc, curr) => ({
    ...acc,
    [curr]: companyImageMap[curr]
  }),
  {}
);


const Ship = ({ ship }) => {
  const shipName = ship.NAME;
  const company = shipCompanyMap[shipName];
  const shipImage = companyImageMap[company];

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={glddImage} alt="Logo" /> // <-- I think this is where the loop should go
    </div>
  );
};


const ShipTracker = ({ ships }) => {
  const handleRowClick = (rowValue) => {
    console.log(rowValue);
  };
  return (
    <div className="ship-tracker">
      <Table className="flags-table" responsive hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Callsign</th>
            <th>Heading</th>
            <th>SOG</th>
            <th>IMO</th>
            <th>MMSI</th>
            <th>Longitude</th>
            <th>Latitudee</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {ships.map((ship, index) => {
            const { IMO, NAME, CALLSIGN, HEADING, SOG, MMSI, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE } = ship;
            const cells = [ NAME, CALLSIGN, HEADING, SOG, IMO, MMSI, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE ];
            return (
              <tr onClick={() => handleRowClick(ship)} key={index}>
                <th scope="row">{index}</th>
                {cells.map((cell) => <td>{cell}</td>)}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ShipTracker;
```

**What I have done so far:**

1) I believe this is a loop problem. I have tried to loop through the company extracted by the API provided and extracted its position, I was trying to match that company with its logo and show it on a google-map but I am not sure how to organize the loop.

2) After doing some research I came across the filtering function and tried to use a bit but realized that this is not probably what I need as my association should be company <--> logo.

3) I am not passing an object. I suspected that I had to treat it as an array and started working in that direction. But since I am not passing a "real" object but am trying to make an association map, working to pass the object was not a good way.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction for solving this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "match their logo" and "show it on a google-map"?

Comment: @sallf, thanks for reading the question. Every company has a logo. I know their latitude and longitude as answer from the API and would like to show their logo (where they are) on `google-map`.

Comment: I'm still unclear. Is your problem matching data from the AIS API with a logo in your `logos/` folder, or is it sending that logo to Google Maps API? Maybe make a simplified example on codepen?

Comment: Yes :) , sending that logo on `google-map` as I already have latitude and longitude.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code isn't showing that integration. Consider removing the `reactjs` tag from you question and adding `google-maps`, as this isn't a react question. Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854328/how-to-show-an-image-by-clicking-on-a-marker-in-google-maps