# React js - Javascript - HTML: How to send an image(logo) on google-map given latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am building a boat visualizer using [AISHub APIs](https://www.aishub.net/).
After inquiring thie APIs I am able to obtain a `json` file with the companies I am interested in.
After injecting these companies into a table on my `HTML` page, I would like to visualize where they are on a `google-map`. I downloaded their logo and given latitude/longitude I would like to see their logo on my `google-map`. How do I visualize the images of their logo on the map?

This the lay-out of my application if useful:

[image: lay-out]

Below the most important part of the code:

**ShipTracker.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table } from 'reactstrap';
import '../components/ShipTracker.css';

import donjonImage from '../logos/donjon.jpg';
import dutraImage from '../logos/dutra.png';
import glddImage from '../logos/greatlakesdredgeanddock.png';


const shipCompanyMap = {
  Michigan: 'DONJON',
  STUYVESANT: 'DUTRA',
  Ellis_Island: 'GREATLAKESDREDGEANDDOCK'
};

const companyImageMap = {
  DONJON: donjonImage,
  DUTRA: dutraImage,
  GREATLAKESDREDGEANDDOCK: glddImage,
};

const associationMap = Object.values(shipCompanyMap).reduce(
  (acc, curr) => ({
    ...acc,
    [curr]: companyImageMap[curr]
  }),
  {}
);


const Ship = ({ ship }) => {
  const shipName = ship.NAME;
  const company = shipCompanyMap[shipName];
  const shipImage = companyImageMap[company];

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={glddImage} alt="Logo" /> // <-- I think this is where the loop should go
    </div>
  );
};


const ShipTracker = ({ ships }) => {
  const handleRowClick = (rowValue) => {
    console.log(rowValue);
  };
  return (
    <div className="ship-tracker">
      <Table className="flags-table" responsive hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Callsign</th>
            <th>Heading</th>
            <th>SOG</th>
            <th>IMO</th>
            <th>MMSI</th>
            <th>Longitude</th>
            <th>Latitudee</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {ships.map((ship, index) => {
            const { IMO, NAME, CALLSIGN, HEADING, SOG, MMSI, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE } = ship;
            const cells = [ NAME, CALLSIGN, HEADING, SOG, IMO, MMSI, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE ];
            return (
              <tr onClick={() => handleRowClick(ship)} key={index}>
                <th scope="row">{index}</th>
                {cells.map((cell) => <td>{cell}</td>)}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ShipTracker;
```

**GoogleMap.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import ShipTracker from '../components/ShipTracker';
import SideBar from '../components/SideBar';


const MapContainer = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 200px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-areas: "google-map   sidebar" "ship-tracker sidebar";

    .google-map {
        background: #424242;
        grid-area: google-map;
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .map-sidebar {
        background: #9dc183;
        grid-area: sidebar;
    }
    .ship-tracker {
        grid-area: ship-tracker;
    }
`;

class BoatMap extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            buttonEnabled: true,
            buttonClickedAt: null,
            progress: 0,
            ships: []
        };
        this.updateRequest = this.updateRequest.bind(this);
        this.countDownInterval = null;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.countDownInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (!this.state.buttonClickedAt) return;
            const date = new Date();
            const diff = Math.floor((date.getTime() - this.state.buttonClickedAt.getTime()) / 1000);

            if (diff < 90) {
                this.setState({
                    progress: diff,
                    buttonEnabled: false
                });
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    progress: 0,
                    buttonClickedAt: null,
                    buttonEnabled: true
                });
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.countdownInterval);
    }

    async updateRequest() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:3001/hello';
        console.log(url);
        const fetchingData = await fetch(url);
        const ships = await fetchingData.json();

        console.log(ships);

        this.setState({
            buttonEnabled: false,
            buttonClickedAt: new Date(),
            progress: 0,
            ships
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ buttonEnabled: true });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="google-map">
                <GoogleMapReact
                    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'My_KEY' }}
                    center={{
                        lat: 42.4,
                        lng: -71.1
                    }}
                    zoom={8}
                >
                </GoogleMapReact>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default class GoogleMap extends React.Component {
    state = {
        ships: []
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:3001/hello';
        console.log(url);
        const fetchingData = await fetch(url);
        const ships = await fetchingData.json();

        console.log(ships);

        this.setState({
            ships
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MapContainer>
                {/* This is the Google Map Tracking Page */}
                <BoatMap />
                <SideBar />
                <ShipTracker ships={this.state.ships} />
            </MapContainer>
        );
    }
}
```

**What I have done so far:**

1) I believe this is a loop problem. I have tried to loop through the company extracted by the API provided and extracted its position, I was trying to match that company with its logo and show it on a google-map but I am not sure how to organize the loop.

2) Another post I found to understand the problem is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854328/how-to-show-an-image-by-clicking-on-a-marker-in-google-maps) but still could not figure out how.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction for solving this problem.

Comment: You talk about google map but I don't see anything related to google map in code you've posted

Comment: [How to add custom markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers) (from Goggle Maps docs, so no react)

Comment: React component someone created to solve this kind of problem - [google-map-react](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react)

Comment: I updated the question with the `GoogleMap.js` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
   <GoogleMapReact
      bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'My_KEY' }}
      center={{
        lat: 42.4,
        lng: -71.1
      }}
      zoom={8}
      >
    {this.state.ships.map(ship => <Ship ship={ship} key={ship.CALLSIGN} lat={ship.LATITUDE} lng={ship.LONGITUDE} />)}
    </GoogleMapReact>
```

Comment: thanks, one last question, how can I pass `const Ship` from `ShipTracker.js` to the `GoogleMap.js` easily?

Comment: @Emanuele I would suggest to move it to separate file because I don't see reasons for it to be in ShipTracker.js. Or you can export it using `export {Ship};` and import using `import {Ship} from './ShipTracker';`

Comment: Ok thanks, I just divided in two files as you suggested as it is more clean now. However I still can't see the logo on `google-map`, I think it is because the variable `const shipImage = companyImageMap[company]` is never used on the file `ShipTracker.js` and therefore the `return` statement `img src={glddImage} alt="Logo" /> // <-- I think this is where the loop should go` never shows it...any idea?

Comment: @Emanuele I don't know... can you prepare an example using codesandbox.io ? It's hard to debug app when you can't click through

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I didn't copy/paste correctly! Your solution works perfectly!! :)